# Selecting the value of "type" attribute from XML file using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

XML:

```
<laptop category="business">
        <name lang="en">HP Pavilion 15</name>
        <color>Silver</color>
        <processor>i5-1135G7</processor>
        <price type ="pln">3200</price>
        <price type ="usd">795</price>
        <price type ="euro">700</price>
</laptop>
```

XSL:

```
<h2><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h2>
<p>Color: <xsl:value-of select="color"/></p>
<p>Processor: <xsl:value-of select="processor"/></p>
```

I want to show as above, 3 different prices in XSL based on attribute type, how can i do it? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not entirely clear.

To show a specific price, you could use a [predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#predicates) - for example (from the context of `laptop`), the instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="price[@type='pln']"/>
```

will return `3200`.

To show all prices, you could something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="price">
    <p>
        <xsl:text>Price: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
    </p>
</xsl:for-each>
```

to get:

[image]